# Changing of positive degree to comparitive

Tags: grammar

What is the comparative degree transformation of "  lion is as strong as   tiger .? is it " lion  is not stronger than tiger or tiger is not stronger than lion. ? Are both of them correct? or any one of them is correct and why?

Answer (score 1):

"Comparative transformation" is something that you do to adjectives:  Strong → Stronger etc.  But you have a complete clause. So you can't do a "comparative transformation".

On the other hand, if that clause expresses strength(lion) = strength(tiger), then there are plenty of ways to express strength(lion) > strength(tiger),  "Lions are stronger than tigers" is probably the most simple.  Or strength(lion) ≥ strength(tiger):  "Tigers aren't stronger than lions".  (which is your suggestion).  Saying "Lions aren't stronger than tigers has the opposite meaning.

You can also say for strength(lion) > strength(tiger) "Tigers are not as strong as lions".

But all of these are just ways to express the notion of "more than", and not a "transformation".